# model.js dynamic connection script location command

Tags: dynamic, model, connection, wakanda

We are structuring our Wakanda project so that the code among all of our projects resides at a directory level above the solution.

During development the code will be within the Project, inside the Solution.

When we deploy, we will flip a flag in `boot.js` to get the code for all Projects across solutions, from a common location above the solution.

`C:/…/wak/Projects/Oaks.js` // connection script for the model.js
`C:/…/wak/Framework/` // Framework directory – single location for all   projects, used during production
`C:/…/wak/Framework/Common/…js` // common js files
`C:/…/wak/Framework/Modules/Billing/` //module specific jsfiles
`C:/…/wak/Framework/Modules/Services/` // module specific jsfiles
`C:/…/wak/SM_Wak/` // solution directory
`C:/…/wak/SM_Wak/admin` // administrative project
`C:/…/wak/SM_Wak/Oaks` // Oaks project
`C:/…/wak/SM_Wak/Oaks/Framework` // Oaks project Frameworkdirectory (used during development)

We have a Project named Oaks.

Using generic code in `Model.js` we want to get the `Oaks.js` 4D connection script for the `mergeOutsideCatalog` from `C:/…/wak/Projects/Oaks.js`

```
var projFolder = getFolder(); // this would be ideal, 
                              // but this command does not work in model.js

var appName = application.name; // this would be very good,
                                // but this command does not work in model.js
```

What command in Wakanda is available in `model.js` that will allow us to dynamically discover the Project currently executing, so that we can derive the correct `model.js` connection script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no solution to your issue. `Model.js` is processed ahead of time compare to others JS files. Therefore, not every APIs are available in this particular JS context.

I would suggest to use non generic code in `Model.js` which point to generic code with flags for switching between Dev/Prod mode.